# <A> in a <TD> cell Jquery event not firing, but every other link does

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working with Jquery.
I have several link with class "ajax-link" that does reload  #content div.
However, another link in a `<td>` doesn't fire my event (even if it has "ajax-link" class same as the other) and reload all page.
How can I fix it ?

I tried several way, the last one is:

```
$('table > tr > td > a.ajax-link').click(function (event) {
```

working one (not in table):

```
$('.ajax-link').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#content').load($(this).attr('href')+ ' #content > *');
});
```

```html
<li>
    <a href="http://laravel:8000/employees" class='ajax-link'>Employees</a>
</li>
```

not working:

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr>
         <td class="id">
             <a href="http://laravel:8000/projects/1" class='ajax-link'>Project 1</a>
         </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I expect that also `<a>` link in `<td>` works like other and reload `#content` div.

Comment: Generally there's a `<tbody>` element between the `<table>` and the `<tr>`

Comment: There is probably another click handler, either on the table or on the table links, that might do `stopPropagation();` and prevents this handler to work. Try inspecting your element in developper tools to search for this

Comment: Also when dynamic content is involved you save yourself headaches by using delegation: `$(document).on("click", ".ajax-link", function(event) { ... })`

Comment: @Davide Guastalli use this selector `table > tbody > tr > td > a.ajax-link`

Comment: dynamic generated html need delegation which may be complex, you can use inline event binding like '<a href="http://laravel:8000/projects/1" class='ajax-link' onclick="onclickmethod()">Project 1</a>', this will work.